# sfc /scannow for Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 16.04

In Windows,  sfc /scannow will check the system files with those available in OS disk and replace faulty, missing files. Is there anything similar available for Ubuntu 16.04 ?

Answer (score 10):

There are two things to do to replicate `sfc /scannow`:

1. `sudo debsums -s` (`sudo apt install debsums` to install it) will list system files that have been changed or corrupted as well as what packages they come from. If none are listed, all system files are fine.

   Use `sudo debsums -sa` to check configuration files as well.
2. `sudo apt reinstall [package]` will reinstall the package, reinstalling the file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a guide pretty easily with google search: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilesystemTroubleshooting

Have you seen that guide?

Comment: I was trying to correct OS files. Not sure this guide is the one I am looking for.

Comment: You are asking for an equivalent of Windows's sfc. I think you are searching for fsck which is explained in that guide. There still might other tools.

Comment: I see. I could'nt quite understand what that guide says. I am not a pro with this. Thanks for the input.

Comment: From what I read so far, it simply correct partition related errors. Just like the disc check we used to get in XP. I could be wrong though.

Comment: You are right this would be the equivalent of chkdsk.